# How can i access field from another model in mongoose model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I made have here two MongoDB Models

Movie Model

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please Enter the Movie Title'],
    trim: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 255
  },
  genre: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Genre',
    required: true
  },
  year: {
    type: Number,
    min: 1800,
    max: 3000,
    required: [true, 'Please enter the year of the movie.']
  },
  directors: [
    {
      type: String,
      minlength: 5,
      maxlength: 100
    }
  ],
  writers: [
    {
      type: String,
      minlength: 5,
      maxlength: 100
    }
  ],
  cast: [
    {
      type: String,
      minlength: 5,
      maxlength: 100
    }
  ],
  numberInStock: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 255
  },
  dailyRentalRate: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 255
  }
});

export default mongoose.model('Movie', movieSchema);
```

Rental Model

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import moment from 'moment';

const rentalSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  customer: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Customer',
    required: true
  },
  movie: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Movie',
    required: true
  },
  dateOut: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: Date.now
  },
  dateReturned: {
    type: Date
  },
  rentalFee: {
    type: Number,
    min: 0
  }
});


rentalSchema.methods.return = function () {
  this.dateReturned = new Date();

  this.rentalFee =
    moment().diff(this.dateOut, 'days') * this.movie.dailyRentalRate;
};

export default mongoose.model('Rental', rentalSchema);
```

Return Controller

```
import catchAsync from '../utils/catchAsync.js';
import AppError from '../utils/appError.js';
import Rental from '../models/rentalModel.js';
import Movie from '../models/movieModel.js';

const returns = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const rental = await Rental.findOne({
    customer: req.body.customerID,
    movie: req.body.movieID
  });
  // console.log(rental);
  if (!rental) {
    return next(new AppError('Not Found', 400));
  }

  if (rental.dateReturned) {
    return next(new AppError('Already Returned', 400));
  }

  rental.return();
  await rental.save();
  // add movie back into stock
  await Movie.updateOne(
    { _id: rental.movie._id },
    {
      $inc: { numberInStock: 1 }
    }
  );

  res.status(400).json({
    status: 'success',
    rental
  });
});

export default returns;
```

Return Route

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import { protect } from '../controllers/authController.js';
import returns from '../controllers/returnController.js';

const router = Router();

router.post('/', protect, returns);

export default router;
```

The problem is that when i want to access the movie field in Rental Model it will return the movie ID
but i want it to return object contains the movie data (something like populate but inside the Model Logic)
so if i tried to access this.movie.dailyRentalRate it returns value not undefined

Comment: please add your controller or route to review your code

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I advise you to read the how to ask a good question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: okay done, i added them

Comment: do you need a get route that has populate()?

Comment: no i want to get the value of this.movie.dailyRentalRate
and i cannot find a way to make that inside the model 
because in rental model, this.movie is just an ObjectID so i want to find a way to make populate inside the rental model, so that this.movie returns an object contains the movie data, and with that i can access the dailyRentalRate

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB has the `$lookup` `aggregation` operator. Mongoose has alternative called `populate()`, which lets you ref documents in other collections.Population is the process of automatically replacing the specified paths in the document with document(s) from other collection(s) so you can use populate for your problem like this:

```
 const rental = await Rental.findOne({
    customer: req.body.customerID,
    movie: req.body.movieID
  }).populate("movie")
```

it's worked to me, and in the `methods.return` you access to the `this.movie.dailyRentalRate`

Comment: rental constant will work on the controller and will return the populated data

Comment: but in the rental model itself you cannot access this.movie.dailyRentalRate
because this.movie will return ObjectID

Comment: That’s right, because movie type in rental model is a monoose.Schema.ObjectId, that have refreance to a other document, like foreign key in relational database, and join tables based on foreign keys. If you want don’t use populate, you should change the movie type in renatal schema, and save other keys in movie key, movie: {
    Id:{type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    required: true},    dailyRentalRate: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 255
  }
  }